# Choosing players based on percentage

Tags: java, hashmap, probability

In my minigame I have multiple players, they bet money. This money then goes into a jackpot, in which I used a Map to get the jackpot. After that, to get a percentage of them winning, I get the bet amount divided by the jackpot. how do I make the program to choose a player based on the percentage given?

**EXAMPLE:**

*player 1 : bets $25*

JACKPOT IS : $25

*player 2 : bets $45*

JACKPOT IS : $70

*player 3 : bets $20*

JACKPOT IS : $90

*player 4 : bets $21*

JACKPOT IS : $111

These players get a percentage of winning, but how do I program it where player 2 has the highest chance of winning etc

```
package dogboy602k.MassBet.Util;

import dogboy602k.MassBet.Main.MassBet;
import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by dogboy on 6/18/2016.
 */
public class Manager {
private Economy economy = null;
private Player p;
private MassBet plugin;
private HashMap<UUID, Double> playerBet;

public Manager(MassBet plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
    this.playerBet = new HashMap<>();
}

public void returninfo(Player player) {
    UUID playerUUID = player.getUniqueId();
    String Player = player.getName();

    if (!playerBet.containsKey(playerUUID)) {
        double jackpot = getTotalPotAmount();
        int howManyBettors = getamountofPlayers();
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.RED + "[ERROR] Seems to be you havent betted, use " + ChatColor.GREEN + "/mass bet " + player.getName() + " <amount>"+ChatColor.RED+" to bet and to be added to the Jack pot");
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.AQUA + "[INFO] The Jackpot is " + ChatColor.GREEN + "$" + jackpot);
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.AQUA + "[INFO] There are " + ChatColor.GREEN + howManyBettors);
        return;
    } else if (playerBet.containsKey(playerUUID)) {
        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        defaultFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        double bet = getPlayerBet(playerUUID);
        double jackpot = getTotalPotAmount();
        int howManyBettors = getamountofPlayers();
        double chance = bet/jackpot;
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.AQUA + "[INFO] Your chances are : " +defaultFormat.format(chance));
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.AQUA + "[INFO] You have bet " + ChatColor.GREEN + "$" + bet);
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.AQUA + "[INFO] The Jackpot is " + ChatColor.GREEN + "$" + jackpot);
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.AQUA + "[INFO] There are " + ChatColor.GREEN + howManyBettors);
    }


}

public void SendBet(Player player, double betAmount) {
    UUID playerUUID = player.getUniqueId();
    String Player = player.getName();
    // check of the player got enough me money
    if (!hasEnoughMoney(player, betAmount)) {

        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.RED + "Not Enough Money.");
    }
    if (hasEnoughMoney(player, betAmount)) {
        /**  To see  the Map printed put
         *
         * for (Map.Entry<UUID, Double> entry : playerBet.entrySet()) {
         *     String key = entry.getKey().toString();
         *     Double value = entry.getValue();
         *     System.out.println("key, " + key + " value " + value);
         *     }
        **/

        if (playerBet.containsKey(playerUUID)) {
            double bet = getPlayerBet(playerUUID);

            Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.RED + "[ERROR] You have betted already");
            Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.RED + "[ERROR] Use " + ChatColor.GREEN + "/mass retract " + player.getName() + ChatColor.RED + " to remove your bet");
            Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.RED + "[ERROR] Your previous  bet amount was: " + ChatColor.GREEN + "$" + bet);
            return;
        } else if (!playerBet.containsKey(playerUUID)) {
            NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
            defaultFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

            addPlayerToPot(playerUUID, betAmount);
            double bet = getPlayerBet(playerUUID);
            double jackpot = getTotalPotAmount();
            double chance = bet/jackpot;
            Util.sendMsg(player, " Your chances are : " +defaultFormat.format(chance));
            Util.sendMsg(player, " You have bet: " + ChatColor.GREEN + "$" + bet);
            Util.sendMsg(player, getamountofPlayers() + " have bet, totaling :" + ChatColor.GREEN + "$" + jackpot);

            plugin.getEconomy().withdrawPlayer(Player,betAmount);
        }
    }
}

public double getTotalPotAmount() {
    double amount = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<UUID, Double> values : playerBet.entrySet()) {
        amount = values.getValue() + amount;
    }
    return amount;
}

public boolean hasEnoughMoney(Player player, double amount) {
    if (plugin.getEconomy().getBalance(player.getName()) >= amount) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void addPlayerToPot(UUID playerUUID, double amount) {
    this.playerBet.put(playerUUID, amount);
}

public void removePlayerFromPot(UUID playerUUID) {
    this.playerBet.remove(playerUUID);
}

public Double getPlayerBet(UUID playerUUID) {
    return this.playerBet.get(playerUUID);
}

public HashMap<UUID, Double > getPlayerBet() {
    return this.playerBet;
}

public int getamountofPlayers() {
    return this.playerBet.size();
}
public void returnTheCashInRetract(Player player){
    UUID playerUUID = player.getUniqueId();
    String Player = player.getName();
    if (playerBet.containsKey(playerUUID)) {
        double bet = getPlayerBet(playerUUID);

        plugin.getEconomy().depositPlayer(player, bet);
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.AQUA + "You have received " + ChatColor.GREEN + "$" + bet + ChatColor.AQUA + " due to your retract");
        Util.sendMsg(player, "You have been removed from the Jackpot and game");
        return;
    }
    else {
        Util.sendMsg(player, ChatColor.RED + "[ERROR] Seems to be you havent betted, use " + ChatColor.GREEN + "/mass bet " + player.getName() + " <amount>"+ChatColor.RED+" to bet and to be added to the Jack pot");
        return;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: can you post some code on how you're using the hashmap?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is the jackpot winner-takes-all, or can there be "side pots" as in poker? As it stands this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I think you need to find maximum bet and you have the player. It's as simple as that, why do you need percentage? Do you need to show it somewhere?

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal yes for a school project

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a Map of chances as key and UUID as value.

```
 private HashMap<Double, UUID> chancesOfPlayer=new HashMap<Double, UUID>();;
```

in sendBet function, create a local map and replace original map with localMap

```
     HashMap<Double, UUID> cop = new HashMap<Double, UUID>();
            for (Map.Entry<UUID,Double> e : playerBet.entrySet()) {
                UUID uid=e.getKey();
                Double userBet=e.getValue();
                Double userChance=userBet/jackpot;
                cop.put(userChance, uid);
            }
            chancesOfPlayer=cop;
```

then you can do

```
     chancesOfPlayer.get(chance); to get the player UUID given percentage.
```

Still **there is complexity left for multiple threads** during access to this hashMap which need to be recalculated each time when there is a new Bet.

Comment: I already mentioned, you can call chancesOfPlayer.get(chance); when you need to get a player uuid given you have chance

Comment: How you want to use it

Comment: @mike, do you have a solution for this?

Comment: yes i do i used a hash map, and divided the sum of the map with the bet put in, that is put in another hashmap, and is rounded and set as a whole number. then in a for loop it is added in a array, then i have a math. random pick a random "box" from the array and that is the winner